# PHP - Iterating twice a generic iterable

Tags: php, iterator, generator, iterable

In PHP 7.1 there is a new [iterable](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.iterable.php) psudo-type which abstracts arrays and `Traversable` objects.

Suppose that in my code I have a class like the following:

```
class Foo
{
    private $iterable;

    public function __construct(iterable $iterable)
    {
        $this->iterable = $iterable;
    }

    public function firstMethod()
    {
        foreach ($this->iterable as $item) {...}
    }

    public function secondMethod()
    {
        foreach ($this->iterable as $item) {...}
    }
}
```

This works fine is `$iterable` is an array or an `Iterator`, except when `$iterable` is a `Generator`. In that case in fact, calling `firstMethod()` and then `secondMethod()` would produce the following `Exception: Cannot traverse an already closed generator`.

Is there a way to avoid this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generators can't be rewound. If you want to avoid this issue, you have to make a new generator. This can be done automatically if you create an object that implements IteratorAggregate:

```
class Iter implements IteratorAggregate
{
    public function getIterator()
    {
        foreach ([1, 2, 3, 4, 5] as $i) {
            yield $i;
        }
    }
}
```

Then just pass an instance of this object as your iterator:

```
$iter = new Iter();
$foo = new Foo($iter);
$foo->firstMethod();
$foo->secondMethod();
```

Output:

```
1
2
3
4
5
1
2
3
4
5
```

Answer (score 0):

After some research, I've found:

- non-working native [CachingIterator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.cachingiterator.php), which does just keep values inside, but doesn't return them on consecutive iteration.
- splendid [CachingIteratorAggregate](https://github.com/loophp/iterators#cachingiteratoraggregate) from `loophp/iterators` library. It does the exact same thing we expect it to - keeps iteration results and returns them on second iteration.

Hence, consider checking out https://github.com/loophp/iterators